# C# Raising Events with custom delegate type on fake object with fakeiteasy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

According to the documentation of fakeiteasy all I have to do is:

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);

event CustomEventHandler CustomEvent;

fake.CustomEvent += Raise.With<CustomEventHandler>(fake, sampleCustomEventArgs);
```

I tried this in my code as follows:

```
public delegate void RowStateHandler(object sender, RowStateHandlerArgs e);
public class RowStateHandlerArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string CampaignId { get; set; }
}
```

...
The interface of the view:

```
public interface ICampaignChannelView
{
     event RowStateHandler RowStateChanged;
}
```

The snippet in my unit test:

```
ICampaignChannelView v = A.Fake<ICampaignChannelView>();
RowStateHandlerArgs args = new RowStateHandlerArgs() {CampaignId = "1", Selected = true};
v.RowStateChanged += Raise.With<RowStateHandler>(v, args);
```

I get following compile error:

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
FakeItEasy.Raise<Add_in.UI.Wizard.RowStateHandler> to
Add_in.UI.Wizard.RowStateHandler    Add-inTests C:\..\WizardPresenterTests.cs
```

and

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'Add_in.UI.Wizard.RowStateHandlerArgs' to
>   'Add_in.UI.Wizard.RowStateHandler'    Add-inTests C:..\WizardPresenterTests.cs

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using an older version of FakeItEasy than that documentation refers to. The [Raising Events documentation page](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Raising-Events) has two flavours. One for FakeItEasy [1.x](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Raising-Events-in-version-1.x) and one for [2.x](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Raising-Events).

> (**Update**: the documentation has since been [moved to readthedocs](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/raising-events/), which has a better system for maintaining different versions of the documentation.)

I just checked the two pages and built two test projects with your code. The only line I ended up changing was

```
 v.RowStateChanged += Raise.With<RowStateHandler>(v, args);
```

Under FakeItEasy 1.25.3, this call works:

```
v.RowStateChanged += Raise.With(v, args).Now;
```

Under FakeItEasy 2.0.0, this call works:

```
v.RowStateChanged += Raise.With<RowStateHandler>(v, args);
```

Comment: Yeah, we upgraded to 2.0.0-rc1 and now it works. At first, it wasnt obvious to us, that the docs we read were for 2.0. Thanks.